# Can't get my data-binding with knockoutJS to work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I'm currently working on an application with DurandalJS, BreezeJS and KnockoutJS.

Everything goes fine but the most simple thing (I believe), I can't get it to work.

In my Viewmodel I have a currentCustomer which is a ko.observable.
Via Breeze I get the customer! `currentCustomer(data.results[0].Customer());` This is all working fine. If I check with Google Chrome I see the object is filled with the currentCustomer.

What I want is the following: I have an inputfield and with a value data-bind I'm trying to bind the Name of the currentCustomer to this input. But I can't get this to work. What works is this:

```
 <input data-bind="value: currentCustomer()" />
```

But in the input field it only says [Object object] So there is definitely something in the currentCustomer (which is).

This is what I tried but didn't work:

```
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer().Name()" />
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer().Name" />
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer.Name()" />
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer.Name" />
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer()._latestValue().Name()" />
<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer()._latestValue.Name()" />
```

Here is a screenshot so you can see the values are in the view!

http://s22.postimg.org/62m21nnsx/problem_data_bind.png

Comment: The `<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer().Name" />` should work please double check it. Also you can try out with  `<input data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(currentCustomer)" />` and update the post with the output.

Comment: No that didn't work! I will try out ko.toJSON right now!

Nop, ko.json returns NULL :S

Comment: Do you maybe have a pluralsight account? For this kind of information you should really have a look at John Papa's site: http://www.johnpapa.net. He is also active here, so I think he will respond to this kind of questions.

Comment: @NickN. I dont have a pluralsight account. I hope he does, I learned a lot from his Hot Towel template;).

Comment: Please try it with also  `<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer() && currentCustomer().Name" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using 'with'?

```
<div data-bind='with:currentCustomer'>
<input data-bind="value: Name/Name()" />
</div>
```

Comment: `<div data-bind='with: currentCustomer'>
   <input data-bind="value: Name" />
</div>`

This did the trick ;) Thank you :) But could you also please explain why the other answers didn't?

Comment: Because you used data-bind="value: text: currentCustomer().name" instead of data-bind="value: currentCustomer().name"

Comment: Where did I used data-bind="value:text: currentCustomer().name" ?

Comment: Read your first response to my answer below.

Comment: Thats strange! THis is what I get when I have this `<input data-bind="value: currentCustomer().Name"/>`

In Google debug: `Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Unable to get property 'Name' of undefined or null reference;
Bindings value: value: currentCustomer().Name,views/estimatepage,[object Object] `

Is this a possible bug in Knockout?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, lunch and meetings...  I can't say exactly why this is the fix, but is something I've had to use to work around the issue you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to currentCustomer().name and that should work provided that Name is a property on the currentCustomer entity.

Comment: No, that didn't work :S 

`Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference;
Bindings value: text: currentCustomer().name,views/estimatepage,[object Object] `

Comment: property of undefined means that your currentCustomer() is null.

Comment: As another note if current customer has a property 'Name' and you are using camelCase as your default convention then currentCustomer().name is the correct way to use it, if you are getting the above error your ko.observable() is empty.  Are you trying to look at a property of the entity before it has been 'filled' with data?

Comment: Yes I know but see the screenshot I posted with!
Also when I only call currentCustomer() it says [Object Object]

Comment: In your screen shot you are looking at a property called latestValue that you do not need to be accessing.

Comment: The answer of @TNCodeMonkey works, so my object is definitely filled

Comment: His answer is one way to do it, using my answer is the correct way to do it depending on how you want to use it.  If you want to use a bunch of properties of currentCustomer than using with: is correct, if you want to display name only just once than you do it the above way.  You got the error above because you used value: text: as your binding instead of value: